# Different ways of Currying

Tags: scala, currying

What is the difference between the below mentioned methods?

I searched for currying in scala and i got these two syntaxes for currying.

```
def add1(x:Int)(y:Int) = {x+y}
def add2(x:Int) = (y:Int) => {x+y}
```

I want to know what is the difference between the two methods

Comment: The first one is a **method** with two _parameters groups_. The second one is a **method** with one _parameter group_ which returns a **function** of one _parameter_. If you do this: `val f: Int => Int = add1(x)` Then you are creating a **function** out of the first method due something called _eta-expansion_. So, while they are completely different, they are somewhat equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Curried functions are functions which can be applied a bit like this

```
f(1)(2)(3)...(n)
```

that is we can apply one argument at a time. Let us try and apply your methods one argument at a time and see what happens

```
add1(1) // error
add2(1) // ok
```

thus we were not quite able to do it with `add1` despite the fact we can write

```
add1(1)(2) // res0: Int = 3
add2(1)(2) // res1: Int = 3
```

However invoking eta expansion explicitly like so

```
val f1 = add1 _ // f1: Int => (Int => Int) = <function>
val f2 = add2 _ // f2: Int => (Int => Int) = <function>
```

we see we get equivalent curried functions, thus

```
f1(1) // ok
f2(1) // ok
```

Comment: You can also `val f: Int => Int = add1(1)` or `val f = add1(x) _`